# neo4jClien Create node with paramaters using a List<Properties>

Tags: list, properties, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to create a node that takes a list of properties and uses the list object to create those properties. Is there any way to do this?

```
public List<PropertiesModel> node_properties;

public class PropertiesModel{ 
    public string propertyName { get; set; }
    public string propertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

then when I pass this on to:

```
client.Cypher
.Create("(n:Label {node})")
         .WithParam("node", node_properties)
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I get the following error when I run this:

CypherTypeException: Collections containing mixed types can not be stored in properties.

I am guessing since this is a list, containing a model made of strings it does not like it. Is there another way to go about building dynamic models of paramaters? I thought about IDictionary but it seems I may have issues mapping directly from a JSON post into a IDictionary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I am feeling slow. Just answered my own question.

I had

```
class nodeModel{ 
List<PropertiesModel> props {get; set;}
}
class PropertiesModel{    
   public string propertyName { get; set; }
   public string propertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

so I needed to do:

```
client.Cypher
.Create("(n:Label {node})")
     .WithParam("node", node_properties.props)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I had to step into the list basically with the .props

but this was not giving me my intended results. Say my list contained 2 properties that I was intending to have attached to 1 node. This actually created a node per property. To solve this, I mapped this over to a IDictionary.

```
IDictionary<string, string> map = node_properties.props.ToDictionary(p=>p.propertyname, p=>p.propertyValue);
```

then I changed the .WithParams part of the query statement to:

```
.WithParams(map)
```

And The intended result was 1 node made up of a list of properties.